# Selection Sort algorithm not working...warning...I'm a newbie

Tags: javascript, algorithm, selection

My algorithm is not working, I'm a newbie to all algorithms and javascript and I just can't seem to work out why it's not working.

**Here's the Array (23, 19, 35, 12, 30)**

**Max value = 0**

Here's what I have...

```
For K= 0 to n – 2 

  MAX = 0

      For j = 0 to n – k - 2

                         If item[j] > item[MAX]
                         MAX = item[j] 

                  end if
          end for 
      swap n - k - 2 with item[MAX] 
   end for
end SelectionSort
```

Where have I gone wrong? thanks!!!!

Also, if anyone could tell me how to use it in a trace table I would be sooo happy!

Kind regards
Craig

Comment: If this is homework, you should tag it as such.

Comment: Sorry, I'm also new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: is this coffeescript? or pseudo code?

Comment: Pseudo code, I don't know of the other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using max in this expression is causing the problem item[MAX], It would be j. Please give it a consideration and then try again like this, The selection sort [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eKfgz/1/)

```
     var arr = new Array (23, 19, 35, 12, 30);         
     temp = 0;

     for( k = 0; k < arr.length-1; k++)
     {

        for( j = k+1;  j < arr.length; j++)
        {

            if (arr [k] > arr [j])
            {

                 temp = arr[k];
                 arr[k] = arr[j];
                 arr[j] = temp;
            }
         }
     }

for(k = 0; k < arr.length; k++)
    alert(arr[k]);​
```

Comment: It works, could you display it as Pseudocode?... so I can put it into a trace table and understand it.. ?

Comment: I hope this will help you http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090320053351AAQfM1w

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a few errors in your code. First of all the upper limit in both places should be n - k -1  instead of n -k-2(so that you do not move the element with index n-k-1 if it is already the max). Also you should swap item[n-k-1] with item[MAX] (not the index as you have written). I believe something like this should work:

```
 For K= 0 to n – 1 
   MAX = 0
   For j = 0 to n – k - 1
      If item[j] > item[MAX]
        MAX = item[j] 
      end if
   end for 
   swap item[n - k - 1] with item[MAX] 
  end for
end SelectionSort
```

Comment: So if I were to put this into a trace table, and test it, how would I go about that? Sorry I'm a complete newbie to algorithms and I really can't get my head around them.